# Vhost access control

Tags: apache, .htaccess, access-control, vhosts

How do I make it that only a certain address can access one of my vhosts?

I have tried:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Web Server\phpmyadmin"
    ServerName localhost

    <Directory />
    Require all granted
    Require ip 192.168.0.10
    </Directory>


    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

And:

DocumentRoot "C:\Web Server\phpmyadmin"
    ServerName localhost

```
<Directory />
<RequireAll>
Require all granted
Require ip 192.168.0.10
</RequireAll>
</Directory>


# Other directives here
```

But Apache refuses to start.

Answer (score 1):

Once I did try the same via the vhost configuration and failed because of dependencies to other apache configuration files. I ended up using the .htaccess file to restrict access to only my IP - it worked in all scenarios I had until now:

Sample htaccess configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.php
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=111.111.111.111
RewriteRule ^.*$ /maintenance.php [R=302,L]
```

It will redirect any user, whose IP is not 111.111.111.111 to the maintenance.php file, where you can leave a message to the users that access is blocked.

I give you this example because I saw that the question is also tagged with ".htaccess".

Comment: In your specific case, you should not use the 302 status code, but [503](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.4).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/test
  <Directory /var/www/test>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from <IP>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Update** in 2.4 use:

```
<Directory /var/www/test>
    Require ip <IP>
</Directory>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using Apache 2.4.

Comment: Thanks, but even if I allow my IP it still gives me forbidden, and won't let anything connect to it now.